# Is $\mathbb{C}[G]$ dual to $U(\mathfrak{g})$?

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Is $\mathbb{C}[G]$ dual to $U(\mathfrak{g})$? In the case of $G = SL_2$, we have $\mathbb{C}[SL_2] = \langle a,b,c,d\rangle / (ad-bc-1 )$ and  $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2) = \langle E, F, H \rangle$. Is it possible to define a pairing between $\mathbb{C}[SL_2]$ and $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ explicitly? For example, define $(a, E) = $, $(a, F)=$ and so on. Thank you very much.

Comment: What sort of dual would you take? You need to be careful to keep the dimension correct (I know how this works for algebraic groups, using the coordinate algebra instead, but I am not sure for Lie groups).

Comment: Ohh, btw, does $\mathbb{C}[G]$ denote the group algebra or the algebra of functions on the group (is it commutative or cocommutative?)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, thank you very much. $\mathbb{C}[G]$ denotes the algebra of functions on the group. It is commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time passed, but I'll try to give an answer anyway, mimicking Chari, Pressley, *A Guide to Quantum Groups*, Example 4.1.17.

First of all, from the example you gave it seems to me that you are considering polynomial functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$. If this is what you meant, Tobias already mentioned that such a duality exists and you may find it in the above mentioned reference.

Alternatively, you may be interested in smooth functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$. In such a case, one may proceed almost in the same way.

Denote by $A$ the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of smooth functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $A=\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(G)$. We have that $A$ is an augmented $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with augmentation $\varepsilon:A\to \mathbb{C}, f\mapsto f(e)$ ($e$ being the neutral element of $G$). I assume $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Der}(A,\mathbb{C}_{\varepsilon})$, i.e.
$$\mathfrak{g}=\left\{\delta\in A^*\mid\delta(fg)=\delta(f)g(e)+f(e)\delta(g)\right\}.$$
First of all, let us see that $\mathfrak{g}$ is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathcal{L}(G)$ of left invariant derivations in
$$\mathrm{Der}_\Bbbk(A,A)=\left\{X\in\mathrm{Hom}_\Bbbk(A,A)\mid X(fg)=X(f)g+fX(g)\quad\mathrm{and}\quad X(1)=0\right\}.$$
By a left invariant derivation I mean the following: $G$ acts on $A$ by left translation, i.e. for every $x\in G$ and $f\in A$, $\lambda_xf:G\mapsto\mathbb{C},y\mapsto f(x^{-1}y)$. With this convention, $X\in \mathrm{Der}_\Bbbk(A,A)$ is left invariant if $\lambda_x\circ X = X\circ \lambda_x$ for every $x\in G$.

One way is easy: to every $X\in\mathcal{L}(G)$ one associate $X_e:A\to\mathbb{C},f\mapsto (X(f))(e)$. For the other way around, to every $\delta\in\mathfrak{g}$ we associate
$$*\delta:A\to A,f\mapsto \left[f*\delta:x\mapsto\delta\left(\lambda_{x^{-1}}f\right)\right].$$
This construction comes from Humphreys, *Linear Algebraic Groups*, §9.2.

This allows us to work with $\mathcal{L}(G)$ instead of $\mathfrak{g}$, thus I will identify them. To see why this is helpful, notice that now $\mathfrak{g}$ acts as a Lie algebra of derivations on $A$, which extends to an action of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ on $A$ by the universal property of the universal enveloping algebra.

The duality is now given simply by
$$U(\mathfrak{g})\times \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(G)\to \mathbb{C}, (u,f)\mapsto (u\cdot f)(e).$$

I hope this answers your question or at least it helps you to find the answer you were looking for.

Comment: thank you very much. Is $(u\cdot f)(e)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(e^{tu})$?